# definition dependent template deduction failure

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

Within a larger project I got issues when trying to use templates to define multiple classes.
After some tinkering I found out, that my code was working when I changed the order of the template definition.
Since I'm rather trying to find the issue in my implementation than blaming the compiler for doing something wrong, I would really appreciate if someone could give me the reason for the following behavior.

I'm using ggc on ubuntu `gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0` and build the example with the compile feature cxx_std_20.

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the comments on my first post, given the tips on how to improve the way I was asking my question I try to simplify the question with this update.

Given the small example:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t... NUMBERS>
struct NumberList
{};
template <typename... TYPES>
struct TypeList
{};

template <typename ...TYPES, template <typename ...> typename List, std::size_t number, std::size_t... numbers>
//template <std::size_t number, std::size_t... numbers, typename... TYPES, template <typename...> typename List>
constexpr void loadNumbers(const List<TYPES...>& types)
{
    // do something 
}

template <std::size_t... numbers, typename... TYPES>
constexpr void loadNumbersAndTypes(const NumberList<numbers...>& number, const TypeList<TYPES...>& types)
{
  loadNumbers<TYPES..., TypeList<TYPES...>, numbers...>(types);
  //loadNumbers<numbers...>(types);
}

int main()
{
  NumberList<2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10> numbers;
  TypeList<float, double> types;
  loadNumbersAndTypes(numbers, types);

  return 0;
}
```

(tested also in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5YY8x5Gd9))
the compiler is not able to infer the template parameter when calling `loadNumbers`.
The error tells that there is a type/value mismatch, i.e. the first argument expects a type but got '2'.
However, the first template arguments explicitly given when calling the function are clearly types and not the `std::size_t`s as complained by the compiler.

The exact compiler output states:

```bash
<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr void loadNumbersAndTypes(const NumberList<numbers ...>&, const TypeList<TYPES ...>&) [with long unsigned int ...numbers = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; TYPES = {float, double}]':
<source>:28:22:   required from here
<source>:20:56: error: no matching function for call to 'loadNumbers<float, double, TypeList<float, double>, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10>(const TypeList<float, double>&)'
   20 |   loadNumbers<TYPES..., TypeList<TYPES...>, numbers...>(types);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:12:16: note: candidate: 'template<class ... TYPES, template<class ...> class List, long unsigned int number, long unsigned int ...numbers> constexpr void loadNumbers(const List<TYPES ...>&)'
   12 | constexpr void loadNumbers(const List<TYPES...>& types)
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:20:56: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class ... TYPES, template<class ...> class List, long unsigned int number, long unsigned int ...numbers> constexpr void loadNumbers(const List<TYPES ...>&)'
   20 |   loadNumbers<TYPES..., TypeList<TYPES...>, numbers...>(types);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:20:56: note:   expected a type, got '2'
<source>:20:56: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class ... TYPES, template<class ...> class List, long unsigned int number, long unsigned int ...numbers> constexpr void loadNumbers(const List<TYPES ...>&)'
<source>:20:56: note:   expected a type, got '3'
[...]
```

When using the commented lines instead (switching the order in which the template arguments are defined), everything works like a charm.
I'm not understanding, why this order is of such important here.

Comment: please do not remove the includes from the code. They are part of the code. Without the includes the code produces a whole lot of other errors, but not the one your question is about https://godbolt.org/z/Y3aad5cro. Read about [mcve]

Comment: and when I add the includes the code compiles without errors https://godbolt.org/z/vaGsqdcsf

Comment: oh well.... the code you posted is the one that does not have errors. Please post a [mcve] of the code that has the error. It is much simpler to help you when we do not have to apply several modifications on the code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I dont understand how you expect replacing `template <std::size_t number, std::size_t... numbers, ........` with `template <typename ...TYPES, ........` should work. The first has a a `size_t` as first argument, the other has a type as first argument.

Comment: [OT]: Instead of recursion, you might use fold expression: `(printCombination<N, FloatTs>(), ...);`

Comment: It is Cartesian product, not combination...

Comment: Any template argument that comes after the first pack must be deduced, I believe. Since the first pack will want to consume all remaining arguments.

Comment: I don't understand why `loadNumbers` is necessary in the first place. The solution is to pass empty structs into function parameters to deduce template arguments this way, like `loadNumbersAndTypes` already does.

Comment: Well, as suggested by @JaMiT I removed the code inside the function `loadNumbers` to simplify the question concerning the template order. the original code can still be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vaGsqdcsf) as provided by @463035818_is_not_an_ai.

In general, multiple packs can be defined, as with `loadNumbersAndTypes`, I was expecting something similar with `loadNumbers`.
the reason for having a separate function is, that `loadNumbers` considers the first `std::size_t` differently.

Comment: If you were replying to my comment, you should've added `@HolyBlackCat`, otherwise I don't get a notification and might forget about this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the first template arguments explicitly given when calling the function are clearly types and not the std::size_ts as complained by the compiler.

No, you are looking at the code like a human instead of like a compiler. The compiler takes your tidy `<TYPES..., TypeList<TYPES...>, numbers...>` and substitutes in `TYPES` and `numbers`, resulting in a list of types followed by a list of numbers (`TypeList<TYPES...>` is a type, not a template). The compiler then ignores what you wrote and instead uses this list of types and numbers as the template arguments. The same result could be obtained by writing out each template argument instead of using pack expansion. That is, "explicitly given" is not relevant for determining which arguments are "the first template arguments".

It does not help that you specified a type, `TypeList<TYPES...>`, for your template template parameter instead of a template, `TypeList`. However, that is not the main problem here.

---

The main problem is a requirement I'll quote from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Explanation). It basically says that you can have non-pack template parameters, followed by a single paramater pack, followed by parameters (possibly including packs) deduced from function arguments, followed by parameters with defaults.

> In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier [than the final parameter] in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments:

In `loadNumbers`, the parameter pack `TYPES` is not the final parameter. Among the parameters that come after it are `number` and `numbers`, neither of which influence the function arguments, and neither of which have default arguments. Therefore your function template definition is ill-formed.

In order to make your definition work, you need the deduced parameter pack to come after the explicitly-provided pack, as in the commented-out version. The parameter pack `TYPES` (which can be deduced from the function arguments) must appear after the parameter pack `numbers` (which cannot be deduced). The `List` parameter can also be deduced from the function arguments, but it is not a parameter pack, so it may appear either before or after `numbers`.

In a comment, you mentioned `loadNumbersAndTypes()` having two parameter packs. In this case, all template parameters are deduced from the function arguments, so multiple packs are allowed, and the packs can occur in any order.

---

It is unfortunate that the error message did not call out the main problem. However, it is common for ill-formed templates to produce unclear error messages.

Comment: `No, you are looking at the code like a human instead of like a compiler.` true, I was expecting something like this, I just could find the reason for it.
Thanks a lot for the answer, I really appreciate the detailed description. I was missing this detail on cppreference...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, any parameter packs after the first one have to be deduced, since the first pack has to consume all remaining arguments.

`loadNumbers` should be implemented like `loadNumbersAndTypes`, but with an extra `std::size_t number` template parameter (if, as you say, the reason it exists is to extract the first number from the list).

```
template <std::size_t Number, std::size_t ...Numbers, typename ...Types>
constexpr void loadNumbers(const NumberList<Number, Numbers...> &numbers, const TypeList<Types...> &types)
{
    // do something 
}

template <std::size_t ...Numbers, typename ...Types>
constexpr void loadNumbersAndTypes(const NumberList<Numbers...> &numbers, const TypeList<Types...> &types)
{
    return loadNumbers(numbers, types);
}
```